# Excel VBA: Is it possible to refer to a column in a table using the variable name for the table?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in my worksheet called tblMetaData.  I have created a Range variable named rngTblMetaData to refer to this table.  Is it possible to refer to columns within this table using the variable?  For instance in the code below I want to refer to a column in the table "tblMetaData" with the header "Track Name".  I would typically do this with `"WsMetaData.Range("tlbMetaData[Track Name]")"`.  Is it possible to shorten this by using the "rngTblMetaData" variable instead?  Thank you!

Ex:

```
Public Wb                               As Workbook
Public WsMetaData                       As Worksheet

Public rngTblMetaData                   As Range

Sub SetVariables()

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set WsMetaData = Wb.Sheets("MetaData")

Set rngTblMetaData = WsMetaData.Range("tlbMetaData")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an Excel table (which is a ListObject), then you should dim it as such. You can either treat the table as a range on the worksheet, and refer to it as you suggested, or work directly with the ListObject, but that means that you refer to columns by number, so will have to search for your heading:

```
Public Wb As Workbook
Public WsMetaData As Worksheet
Public tblMetaData As ListObject
Public columnData As Range

Sub SetVariables()

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set WsMetaData = Wb.Sheets("MetaData")
    Set tblMetaData = WsMetaData.ListObjects("tblMetaData")

    Set columnData = WsMetaData.Range("tblMetaData[Track Names]")
    'or
    Dim columnNumber As Long
    columnNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("Track Names", tblMetaData.HeaderRowRange, 1)
    Set columnData = tblMetaData.ListColumns(columnNumber).DataBodyRange

End Sub
```